# How do I code so only the combobox's that I select are displayed?

Tags: vb.net

```
textbox1.text = "OS = " combobox1.selecteditem + environment.newline + 
combobox2.selecteditem + environment.newline + combobox3.selecteditem + 
environment.newline
```

Working with Visual Basic 2010
I'm trying to make a display show up as 
"OS =" and lets say I chose "combobox3" I want it to look like 
"OS = Windows"
instead of

"OS =

Windows"

my code done so fare is

Comment: Check if combobox has SelectedItem before adding to the string. Show how items are added to the comboboxes

Comment: write code to check which controls have an item selected

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation should be done with & instead of +.  Also, remove environment.newline to get rid of the line breaks.

```
textbox1.Text = "OS = " & combobox1.SelectedItem & " " & 
combobox2.SelectedItem & " " & combobox3.SelectedItem
```

If I'm misunderstanding the question and you're trying to avoid line breaks where there is no value you would do the following:

```
    Dim strResult As String = "OS = " & Environment.NewLine

    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1

    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        strResult += ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
    End If

    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        strResult += ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
    End If

    If ComboBox3.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        strResult += ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
    End If

    TextBox1.Text = strResult
```

Comment: Well the thing is I want each selected item to have it's own new line.

Comment: Use `&` instead of `+` operator for concatenating strings :) :)

Comment: @Fabio LOL, "Do as I say, not as I do!"

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Linq` personally. You don't have to worry about many `If` statements and checking if something is selected or not and also concatenating a string either or adding or removing `CheckBox's` if you plan to do so; it will grab all of them. If you plan to not include some then you would need to modify the query to fit. This is tried and tested as well.

```
  Dim q As List(Of String) = (From s As ComboBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox).Reverse() Where s.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Select CStr(s.SelectedItem) & Environment.NewLine).ToList
  MsgBox("OS = " & String.Join("", q.ToArray)) 'Just for testing!
```

Comment: What if form contains other combobox which not included in this problem?

Comment: It doesnt matter at all. I said he would need to modify accordingly if he doesnt want to include any others...

Comment: So more `if` statements but only trying to put all inside long unreadable LINQ query?

Comment: Pretty simple if I may say. Give me all comboboxs that are selected and put their value in a collection... I dont see any difference except how its implemented. Essentially i am doing the same as ifs but in one line and 1 time only... if he adds another awesome the query will work, if he removes controls it will work. If i used if statements its more of a hassle because of maintainability... oh i forgot i could have used line breaks to make the code deeper and it wouldnt be as long...